# Transform multiple array Json into a df PYTHON

Tags: python, json, multidimensional-array

Good afternoon all,
I'm trying to import the follow json as a df in Python, but it is giving me a hard time:

```
[
  {
    "id": 403200072,
    "dataPublicacao": "06/04/2021",
    "dataReferencia": "17/08/2022",
    "punicao": {
      "cpfPunidoFormatado": "***.619.560-**",
      "nomePunido": "ELIDIANA MAROSTICA",
      "portaria": "69",
      "processo": "21000.047774/2020-26",
      "paginaDOU": "4",
      "secaoDOU": 2
    },
    "tipoPunicao": {
      "descricao": "DESTITUIÇÃO"
    },
    "pessoa": {
      "id": 4615150,
      "cpfFormatado": "***.619.560-**",
      "cnpjFormatado": "",
      "numeroInscricaoSocial": "",
      "nome": "ELIDIANA MAROSTICA",
      "razaoSocialReceita": "",
      "nomeFantasiaReceita": "",
      "tipo": "Pessoa Física"
    },
    "orgaoLotacao": {
      "siglaDaPasta": "MAPA",
      "sigla": "SFA",
      "nome": "SUPERINTENDÊNCIA FEDERAL DE AGRICULTURA, PECUÁRIA E ABASTECIMENTO",
      "nomeSemAcento": "SUPERINTENDENCIA FEDERAL DE AGRICULTURA, PECUARIA E ABASTECIMENTO"
    },
    "ufLotacaoPessoa": {
      "codigoIBGE": "4300000",
      "codigoCNPJEstado": "87934675000196",
      "populacao": 10609335,
      "uf": {
        "sigla": "RS",
        "nome": "RIO GRANDE DO SUL"
      }
    },
    "cargoEfetivo": "",
    "codigoCargoComissao": "DAS-101.2",
    "cargoComissao": "CHEFE DE DIVISAO",
    "fundamentacao": [
      {
        "codigo": "8429-11-I",
        "descricao": "Praticar ato visando fim proibido em lei ou regulamento ou diverso daquele previsto, na regra de competência"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8429-11-C",
        "descricao": "Caput - Constitui ato de improbidade administrativa que atenta contra os princípios da administração pública qualquer ação ou omissão que viole os deveres de honestidade, imparcialidade, legalidade, e lealdade às instituições."
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-132-X",
        "descricao": "Lesão aos cofres públicos e dilapidação do patrimônio nacional"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-117-XII",
        "descricao": "Receber propina, comissão, presente ou vantagem de qualquer espécie, em razão de suas atribuições"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8429-10-I",
        "descricao": "Facilitar ou concorrer por qualquer forma para a incorporação ao patrimônio particular, de pessoa física ou jurídica, de bens, rendas, verbas ou valores integrantes do acervo patrimonial das entidades mencionadas no art. 1º desta lei."
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-132-IV",
        "descricao": "Improbidade administrativa"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8429-9-I",
        "descricao": "Receber, para si ou para outrem, dinheiro, bem móvel ou imóvel, ou qualquer outra vantagem econômica, direta ou indireta, a título de comissão, percentagem, gratificação ou presente de quem tenha interesse, direto ou indireto, que possa ser atingido ou amparado por ação ou omissão decorrente das atribuições do agente público"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-135",
        "descricao": "A destituição de cargo em comissão exercido por não ocupante de cargo efetivo será aplicada nos casos de infração sujeita às penalidades de suspensão e de demissão"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8429-10-XII",
        "descricao": "Permitir, facilitar ou concorrer para que terceiro se enriqueça ilicitamente"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-132-XIII",
        "descricao": "Transgressão dos incisos IX a XVI do art. 117 "
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-117-IX",
        "descricao": "Valer-se do cargo para lograr proveito pessoal ou de outrem, em detrimento da dignidade da função pública"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-132-XI",
        "descricao": "Corrupção"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 403200073,
    "dataPublicacao": "20/08/2012",
    "dataReferencia": "17/08/2022",
    "punicao": {
      "cpfPunidoFormatado": "***.294.490-**",
      "nomePunido": "FRANCISCO NARBAL ALVES RODRIGUES",
      "portaria": "1813",
      "processo": "08004.001890/2011",
      "paginaDOU": "026",
      "secaoDOU": 2
    },
    "tipoPunicao": {
      "descricao": "DESTITUIÇÃO"
    },
    "pessoa": {
      "id": 1018751,
      "cpfFormatado": "***.294.490-**",
      "cnpjFormatado": "",
      "numeroInscricaoSocial": "",
      "nome": "FRANCISCO NARBAL ALVES RODRIGUES",
      "razaoSocialReceita": "",
      "nomeFantasiaReceita": "",
      "tipo": "Pessoa Física"
    },
    "orgaoLotacao": {
      "siglaDaPasta": "MJSP",
      "sigla": "MJSP",
      "nome": "MINISTÉRIO DA JUSTIÇA E SEGURANÇA PÚBLICA",
      "nomeSemAcento": "MINISTERIO DA JUSTICA E SEGURANCA PUBLICA"
    },
    "ufLotacaoPessoa": {
      "codigoIBGE": "5300000",
      "codigoCNPJEstado": "00394601000126",
      "populacao": 2570160,
      "uf": {
        "sigla": "DF",
        "nome": "DISTRITO FEDERAL"
      }
    },
    "cargoEfetivo": "",
    "codigoCargoComissao": "DAS-102.4",
    "cargoComissao": "Assessor do Secretário-Executivo",
    "fundamentacao": [
      {
        "codigo": "8112-132-IV",
        "descricao": "Improbidade administrativa"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-116-VIII",
        "descricao": "Guardar sigilo sobre assunto da repartição"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-116-III",
        "descricao": "Observar as normas legais e regulamentares"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-117-IX",
        "descricao": "Valer-se do cargo para lograr proveito pessoal ou de outrem, em detrimento da dignidade da função pública"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-116-II",
        "descricao": "Ser leal às instituições a que servir"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 403200075,
    "dataPublicacao": "18/01/2007",
    "dataReferencia": "17/08/2022",
    "punicao": {
      "cpfPunidoFormatado": "***.371.876-**",
      "nomePunido": "LUIZ EDUARDO MACHADO DE CASTRO",
      "portaria": "006",
      "processo": "48400.000215/2006-48",
      "paginaDOU": "026",
      "secaoDOU": 2
    },
    "tipoPunicao": {
      "descricao": "DESTITUIÇÃO"
    },
    "pessoa": {
      "id": 618494,
      "cpfFormatado": "***.371.876-**",
      "cnpjFormatado": "",
      "numeroInscricaoSocial": "",
      "nome": "LUIZ EDUARDO MACHADO DE CASTRO",
      "razaoSocialReceita": "",
      "nomeFantasiaReceita": "",
      "tipo": "Pessoa Física"
    },
    "orgaoLotacao": {
      "siglaDaPasta": "MME",
      "sigla": "DNPM",
      "nome": "DEPARTAMENTO NACIONAL DE PRODUÇÃO MINERAL",
      "nomeSemAcento": "DEPARTAMENTO NACIONAL DE PRODUCAO MINERAL"
    },
    "ufLotacaoPessoa": {
      "codigoIBGE": "3100000",
      "codigoCNPJEstado": "18715615000160",
      "populacao": 19597330,
      "uf": {
        "sigla": "MG",
        "nome": "MINAS GERAIS"
      }
    },
    "cargoEfetivo": "",
    "codigoCargoComissao": "DAS-101.4",
    "cargoComissao": "CHEFE DE DISTRITO",
    "fundamentacao": [
      {
        "codigo": "8112-116-IX",
        "descricao": "Manter conduta compatível com a moralidade administrativa"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-117-XV",
        "descricao": "Proceder de forma desidiosa"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-132-IV",
        "descricao": "Improbidade administrativa"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-116-III",
        "descricao": "Observar as normas legais e regulamentares"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-116-I",
        "descricao": "Exercer com zelo e dedicação as atribuições do cargo"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-116-II",
        "descricao": "Ser leal às instituições a que servir"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 403200076,
    "dataPublicacao": "22/05/2009",
    "dataReferencia": "17/08/2022",
    "punicao": {
      "cpfPunidoFormatado": "***.854.488-**",
      "nomePunido": "SYLVIA PARIZ CAMPOS",
      "portaria": "27",
      "processo": "01400.007683/2006-80",
      "paginaDOU": "006",
      "secaoDOU": 2
    },
    "tipoPunicao": {
      "descricao": "DESTITUIÇÃO"
    },
    "pessoa": {
      "id": 9018575,
      "cpfFormatado": "***.854.488-**",
      "cnpjFormatado": "",
      "numeroInscricaoSocial": "",
      "nome": "SYLVIA PARIZ CAMPOS",
      "razaoSocialReceita": "",
      "nomeFantasiaReceita": "",
      "tipo": "Pessoa Física"
    },
    "orgaoLotacao": {
      "siglaDaPasta": "MCIDADANIA",
      "sigla": "MCIDADANIA",
      "nome": "MINISTÉRIO DA CIDADANIA",
      "nomeSemAcento": "MINISTERIO DA CIDADANIA"
    },
    "ufLotacaoPessoa": {
      "codigoIBGE": "3500000",
      "codigoCNPJEstado": "46379400000150",
      "populacao": 41175694,
      "uf": {
        "sigla": "SP",
        "nome": "SÃO PAULO"
      }
    },
    "cargoEfetivo": "",
    "codigoCargoComissao": "DAS-101.2",
    "cargoComissao": "OUVIDOR DA REPRESENTAÇÃO REGIONAL DO MINISTÉRIO DA CULTURA EM SÃO PAULO",
    "fundamentacao": [
      {
        "codigo": "8429-10-IX",
        "descricao": "Ordenar ou permitir a realização de despesas não autorizadas em lei ou regulamento"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-132-IV",
        "descricao": "Improbidade administrativa"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8429-10-VIII",
        "descricao": "Frustrar a licitude de processo licitatório ou dispensá-lo indevidamente"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 403200106,
    "dataPublicacao": "10/10/2018",
    "dataReferencia": "17/08/2022",
    "punicao": {
      "cpfPunidoFormatado": "***.456.031-**",
      "nomePunido": "JOAQUIM HENRIQUE MONTELO MOURA",
      "portaria": "159",
      "processo": "02001.004308/2015-34",
      "paginaDOU": "45",
      "secaoDOU": 2
    },
    "tipoPunicao": {
      "descricao": "CASSAÇÃO DE APOSENTADORIA"
    },
    "pessoa": {
      "id": 3101309,
      "cpfFormatado": "***.456.031-**",
      "cnpjFormatado": "",
      "numeroInscricaoSocial": "",
      "nome": "JOAQUIM HENRIQUE MONTELO MOURA",
      "razaoSocialReceita": "",
      "nomeFantasiaReceita": "",
      "tipo": "Pessoa Física"
    },
    "orgaoLotacao": {
      "siglaDaPasta": "MMA",
      "sigla": "IBAMA",
      "nome": "INSTITUTO BRASILEIRO DO MEIO AMBIENTE E DOS RECURSOS NATURAIS RENOVÁVEIS",
      "nomeSemAcento": "INSTITUTO BRASILEIRO DO MEIO AMBIENTE E DOS RECURSOS NATURAIS RENOVAVEIS"
    },
    "ufLotacaoPessoa": {
      "codigoIBGE": "5300000",
      "codigoCNPJEstado": "00394601000126",
      "populacao": 2570160,
      "uf": {
        "sigla": "DF",
        "nome": "DISTRITO FEDERAL"
      }
    },
    "cargoEfetivo": "Analista Administrativo",
    "codigoCargoComissao": "",
    "cargoComissao": "",
    "fundamentacao": [
      {
        "codigo": "8429-11-II",
        "descricao": "Retardar ou deixar de praticar, indevidamente, ato de ofício"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8429-11-I",
        "descricao": "Praticar ato visando fim proibido em lei ou regulamento ou diverso daquele previsto, na regra de competência"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8429-11-IV",
        "descricao": "Negar publicidade aos atos oficiais"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-132-XIII",
        "descricao": "Transgressão dos incisos IX a XVI do art. 117 "
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-134",
        "descricao": "Será cassada a aposentadoria ou a disponibilidade do inativo que houver praticado,na atividade, falta punível com a demissão."
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-117-IX",
        "descricao": "Valer-se do cargo para lograr proveito pessoal ou de outrem, em detrimento da dignidade da função pública"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-127-IV",
        "descricao": "Cassação de aposentadoria ou disponibilidade"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-116-II",
        "descricao": "Ser leal às instituições a que servir"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-116-III",
        "descricao": "Observar as normas legais e regulamentares"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-116-IX",
        "descricao": "Manter conduta compatível com a moralidade administrativa"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-132-IV",
        "descricao": "Improbidade administrativa"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-116-I",
        "descricao": "Exercer com zelo e dedicação as atribuições do cargo"
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-117-XV",
        "descricao": "Proceder de forma desidiosa"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 403200107,
    "dataPublicacao": "16/03/2018",
    "dataReferencia": "17/08/2022",
    "punicao": {
      "cpfPunidoFormatado": "***.248.507-**",
      "nomePunido": "BERNADETE FONTENELLE DE MAYRINCK",
      "portaria": "939",
      "processo": "35301.002518/2014-81",
      "paginaDOU": "43",
      "secaoDOU": 2
    },
    "tipoPunicao": {
      "descricao": "CASSAÇÃO DE APOSENTADORIA"
    },
    "pessoa": {
      "id": 4018714,
      "cpfFormatado": "***.248.507-**",
      "cnpjFormatado": "",
      "numeroInscricaoSocial": "",
      "nome": "BERNARDETE FONTENELLE DE MAYRINCK",
      "razaoSocialReceita": "",
      "nomeFantasiaReceita": "",
      "tipo": "Pessoa Física"
    },
    "orgaoLotacao": {
      "siglaDaPasta": "ME",
      "sigla": "INSS",
      "nome": "INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE SEGURO SOCIAL",
      "nomeSemAcento": "INSTITUTO NACIONAL DE SEGURO SOCIAL"
    },
    "ufLotacaoPessoa": {
      "codigoIBGE": "3300000",
      "codigoCNPJEstado": "42498600000171",
      "populacao": 15979640,
      "uf": {
        "sigla": "RJ",
        "nome": "RIO DE JANEIRO"
      }
    },
    "cargoEfetivo": "Técnico do Seguro Social",
    "codigoCargoComissao": "",
    "cargoComissao": "",
    "fundamentacao": [
      {
        "codigo": "8112-134",
        "descricao": "Será cassada a aposentadoria ou a disponibilidade do inativo que houver praticado,na atividade, falta punível com a demissão."
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-132-XIII",
        "descricao": "Transgressão dos incisos IX a XVI do art. 117 "
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-117-IX",
        "descricao": "Valer-se do cargo para lograr proveito pessoal ou de outrem, em detrimento da dignidade da função pública"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 403200108,
    "dataPublicacao": "10/10/2016",
    "dataReferencia": "17/08/2022",
    "punicao": {
      "cpfPunidoFormatado": "***.756.643-**",
      "nomePunido": "AMÁLIA RIBEIRO PARENTE",
      "portaria": "1781",
      "processo": "25016.004876/2011-48",
      "paginaDOU": "45",
      "secaoDOU": 2
    },
    "tipoPunicao": {
      "descricao": "CASSAÇÃO DE APOSENTADORIA"
    },
    "pessoa": {
      "id": 3418577,
      "cpfFormatado": "***.756.643-**",
      "cnpjFormatado": "",
      "numeroInscricaoSocial": "",
      "nome": "AMALIA RIBEIRO PARENTE",
      "razaoSocialReceita": "",
      "nomeFantasiaReceita": "",
      "tipo": "Pessoa Física"
    },
    "orgaoLotacao": {
      "siglaDaPasta": "MS",
      "sigla": "MS",
      "nome": "MINISTÉRIO DA SAÚDE",
      "nomeSemAcento": "MINISTERIO DA SAUDE"
    },
    "ufLotacaoPessoa": {
      "codigoIBGE": "2300000",
      "codigoCNPJEstado": "07954480000179",
      "populacao": 8452381,
      "uf": {
        "sigla": "CE",
        "nome": "CEARÁ"
      }
    },
    "cargoEfetivo": "AUXILIAR OPERACIONAL DE SERVIÇOS DIVERSOS",
    "codigoCargoComissao": "",
    "cargoComissao": "",
    "fundamentacao": [
      {
        "codigo": "8112-134",
        "descricao": "Será cassada a aposentadoria ou a disponibilidade do inativo que houver praticado,na atividade, falta punível com a demissão."
      },
      {
        "codigo": "8112-132-XII",
        "descricao": "Acumulação ilegal de cargos, empregos ou funções públicas"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

considering that this json is the "dados_ceaf", I'm trying the following code:

```
df_ceaf = pd.DataFrame(dados_ceaf)
```

but, it's returnig me this. I don't know how to work with this arrays that contains more information. I have tried to use explode, but it didn't work as I was expecting. Maybe it's because hte data inside this arrays are not between the brackets.

```
    id  dataPublicacao  dataReferencia  punicao tipoPunicao pessoa  orgaoLotacao    ufLotacaoPessoa cargoEfetivo    codigoCargoComissao cargoComissao   fundamentacao
0   403200072   06/04/2021  17/08/2022  {'cpfPunidoFormatado': '***.619.560-**', 'nome...   {'descricao': 'DESTITUIÇÃO'}    {'id': 4615150, 'cpfFormatado': '***.619.560-*...   {'siglaDaPasta': 'MAPA', 'sigla': 'SFA', 'nome...   {'codigoIBGE': '4300000', 'codigoCNPJEstado': ...       DAS-101.2   CHEFE DE DIVISAO    [{'codigo': '8429-11-I', 'descricao': 'Pratica...
1   403200073   20/08/2012  17/08/2022  {'cpfPunidoFormatado': '***.294.490-**', 'nome...   {'descricao': 'DESTITUIÇÃO'}    {'id': 1018751, 'cpfFormatado': '***.294.490-*...   {'siglaDaPasta': 'MJSP', 'sigla': 'MJSP', 'nom...   {'codigoIBGE': '5300000', 'codigoCNPJEstado': ...       DAS-102.4   Assessor do Secretário-Executivo    [{'codigo': '8112-132-IV', 'descricao': 'Impro...
2   403200075   18/01/2007  17/08/2022  {'cpfPunidoFormatado': '***.371.876-**', 'nome...   {'descricao': 'DESTITUIÇÃO'}    {'id': 618494, 'cpfFormatado': '***.371.876-**...   {'siglaDaPasta': 'MME', 'sigla': 'DNPM', 'nome...   {'codigoIBGE': '3100000', 'codigoCNPJEstado': ...       DAS-101.4   CHEFE DE DISTRITO   [{'codigo': '8112-116-IX', 'descricao': 'Mante...
3   403200076   22/05/2009  17/08/2022  {'cpfPunidoFormatado': '***.854.488-**', 'nome...   {'descricao': 'DESTITUIÇÃO'}    {'id': 9018575, 'cpfFormatado': '***.854.488-*...   {'siglaDaPasta': 'MCIDADANIA', 'sigla': 'MCIDA...   {'codigoIBGE': '3500000', 'codigoCNPJEstado': ...       DAS-101.2   OUVIDOR DA REPRESENTAÇÃO REGIONAL DO MINISTÉRI...   [{'codigo': '8429-10-IX', 'descricao': 'Ordena...
4   403200106   10/10/2018  17/08/2022  {'cpfPunidoFormatado': '***.456.031-**', 'nome...   {'descricao': 'CASSAÇÃO DE APOSENTADORIA'}  {'id': 3101309, 'cpfFormatado': '***.456.031-*...   {'siglaDaPasta': 'MMA', 'sigla': 'IBAMA', 'nom...   {'codigoIBGE': '5300000', 'codigoCNPJEstado': ...   Analista Administrativo         [{'codigo': '8429-11-II', 'descricao': 'Retard...
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
5577    431900106   18/04/2019  17/08/2022  {'cpfPunidoFormatado': '***.457.867-**', 'nome...   {'descricao': 'DEMISSÃO'}   {'id': 4018385, 'cpfFormatado': '***.457.867-*...   {'siglaDaPasta': 'MS', 'sigla': 'MS', 'nome': ...   {'codigoIBGE': '3300000', 'codigoCNPJEstado': ...   MEDICO          [{'codigo': '8112-132-II', 'descricao': 'Aband...
5578    431900109   21/03/2017  17/08/2022  {'cpfPunidoFormatado': '***.806.438-**', 'nome...   {'descricao': 'DEMISSÃO'}   {'id': 8604967, 'cpfFormatado': '***.806.438-*...   {'siglaDaPasta': 'MEC', 'sigla': 'UFOPA', 'nom...   {'codigoIBGE': '1500000', 'codigoCNPJEstado': ...   PROFESSOR DO MAGISTERIO SUPERIOR            [{'codigo': '8112-132-II', 'descricao': 'Aband...
5579    431900111   10/11/2014  17/08/2022  {'cpfPunidoFormatado': '***.031.043-**', 'nome...   {'descricao': 'DEMISSÃO'}   {'id': 8212638, 'cpfFormatado': '***.031.043-*...   {'siglaDaPasta': 'MMA', 'sigla': 'ICMBio', 'no...   {'codigoIBGE': '2300000', 'codigoCNPJEstado': ...   TÉCNICO ADMINISTRATIVO          [{'codigo': '8112-132-III', 'descricao': 'Inas...
5580    431900113   28/10/2020  17/08/2022  {'cpfPunidoFormatado': '***.392.642-**', 'nome...   {'descricao': 'DEMISSÃO'}   {'id': 7816123, 'cpfFormatado': '***.392.642-*...   {'siglaDaPasta': 'MMA', 'sigla': 'IBAMA', 'nom...   {'codigoIBGE': '2200000', 'codigoCNPJEstado': ...   TECNICO ADMINISTRATIVO          [{'codigo': '8429-11-C', 'descricao': 'Caput -...
5581    431900116   06/01/2022  17/08/2022  {'cpfPunidoFormatado': '***.893.926-**', 'nome...   {'descricao': 'DEMISSÃO'}   {'id': 4014366, 'cpfFormatado': '***.893.926-*...   {'siglaDaPasta': 'MEC', 'sigla': 'UFOP', 'nome...   {'codigoIBGE': '3100000', 'codigoCNPJEstado': ...   PROFESSOR DO MAGISTERIO SUPERIOR            [{'codigo': '8112-132-XII', 'descricao': 'Acum...
```

Can anybody help me, please?
Regards,
Victor

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html?highlight=json_normalize#) to read JSON and even unpack nested lists. It's going to be like the following:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('dados_ceaf.json') as f:
  dados_ceaf = json.load(f)

# Dataframe with `dados_ceaf` normalized
df_ceaf = pd.json_normalize(dados_ceaf)

# Dataframe with nested list `fundamentacao` normalized plus `id` from `dados_ceaf`
df_fundamentacao = pd.json_normalize(dados_ceaf,
                                     record_path = 'fundamentacao',
                                     meta = ['id'])
```

The first call to `json_normalize` will return the data with the following fields:

```
id
dataPublicacao
dataReferencia
cargoEfetivo
codigoCargoComissao
cargoComissao
fundamentacao
punicao.cpfPunidoFormatado
punicao.nomePunido
punicao.portaria
punicao.processo
punicao.paginaDOU
punicao.secaoDOU
tipoPunicao.descricao
pessoa.id
pessoa.cpfFormatado
pessoa.cnpjFormatado
pessoa.numeroInscricaoSocial
pessoa.nome
pessoa.razaoSocialReceita
pessoa.nomeFantasiaReceita
pessoa.tipo
orgaoLotacao.siglaDaPasta
orgaoLotacao.sigla
orgaoLotacao.nome
orgaoLotacao.nomeSemAcento
ufLotacaoPessoa.codigoIBGE
ufLotacaoPessoa.codigoCNPJEstado
ufLotacaoPessoa.populacao
ufLotacaoPessoa.uf.sigla
ufLotacaoPessoa.uf.nome
```

The second with those fields:

```
codigo
descricao
id
```

Repeat the process for every nested list.